# IntegrityError : column user_id is not unique

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-users

I'm creating Django User registration form. But I can't figure out why Django returns this error when I submit the registration info.

```
IntegrityError : column user_id is not unique
```

and in detail, this part of [views.py] is highlighted in the error page.

```
uasite1 = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user, name=form.cleaned_data['name'],major=form.cleaned_data['major'],email=form.cleaned_data['email'])
```

Could someone give me the reason why this error occurs? Here's my codes:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    major = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from uasite1.models import UserProfile
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=('User Name'))
    password = forms.CharField(label=('Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=('Verify Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user',)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError("That username is already taken, please select another.")

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if "@gmail.com" not in data:
             raise forms.ValidationError("Must include @gmail.com")
        return data

    def clean(self):

        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']

        if password and password1 and password != password1:      
            raise forms.ValidationError("The passwords did not match. Please try again.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from uasite1.forms import RegistrationForm
from uasite1.models import UserProfile
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


def SecondhandRegistration(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(username= form.cleaned_data['username'],email = form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            user.save()

            uasite1 = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user, name=form.cleaned_data['name'],major=form.cleaned_data['major'],email=form.cleaned_data['email'])
            uasite1.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('register.html',{'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('register.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Do you have a signal connected anywhere which creates a user profile in a post save hook?

Comment: I don't think I do. That's something like this ? (django.db.models.signals.post_save : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have cleared the user table and started testing registration again. In that case the previous data will persist in the profile table so there is a possibility this error.